# neomutt: Stop new mail banner for folders other than inbox

Tags: email, gmail, mutt, neomutt

I'm using neomutt as my local mail reader (I use isync to mirror my Gmail account locally). I am noticing that sometimes when I start neomutt, it informs me in the bottom banner that there are new mails in folders other than Inbox (usually, "~/Mail/Archive", which corresponds to my Gmail
"All Mail" label).

Is there a way to configure neomutt such that it will only tell me about new mail in specific folders?

Thanks.

Comment: The `mailboxes` setting determines mailboxes checked for new messages. Check that and also the "New Mail Detection" section in the manual (F1).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible with neomutt at the moment.

It should be possible with mutt 1.14 (see [release notes](http://www.mutt.org/relnotes/1.14/)) and newer using `-poll` argument to a `mailboxes` command. Although neomutt tries to implement all upstream features, this still wasn't done.